# Refresh/Reload/Restart for SVG on click

Tags: javascript, html, svg

There is a stand alone animated svg. Here is the code

```
<div style="width: 504px;">
<object id="conv1" type="image/svg+xml" data="1.svg"></object>
<p style="text-align: center;">
<button><span>Play/Replay</span></button>
</p>
</div>
```

I want to reload/refresh (restart drawing svg) on clicking the button play/replay. Here is the website link.
 http://mathsbeauty.esy.es/temp3.html
What code can be given to Play/Replay button, probably using javascript so as to achieve this?

Comment: What kind of animation/drawing? SMIL, CSS, javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the svg element from the page entirely and re-insert it. Just clone the object element and replace it with the cloned one.

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
   var element = document.querySelector("object");
   var cloneElement = element.cloneNode(true);
   element.parentNode.replaceChild(cloneElement, element); 
}, false);
```

```css
object {
    height: 75vh;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 504px;">
    <object id="conv1" type="image/svg+xml" data="http://mathsbeauty.esy.es/1.svg"></object>
    <p style="text-align: center;">
         <button><span>Play/Replay</span></button>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: I could not get the exact way of implementing your solution...If possible you may add some details..

Comment: What details would you like to know? Is that not what you were looking for?

Comment: How the script can be attached to Play/Replay button?

Comment: It's simple javascript. Just include it in the html file.

Comment: Are there other buttons and objects in the webpage. In that assign id to the button and the object and replace querySelector with getElementById. I don't see any reason for it to not work. Update your website with the code. Then i can see what is going on

Comment: Add javascripts after the body tag.